# Convert from ifstream* to ifstream&

Tags: c++

I want to covert from

```
ifstream* ifs1 = storeManager.getMultiDataReaderStream();
```

to

```
ifstream& ifs1
```

how will i achieve this??

Comment: This question is off-topic because the problem detailed is too narrow and unlikely to help future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you dereference a pointer? Using the dereference operator:

```
ifstream& ifs1 = *storeManager.getMultiDataReaderStream();
                 ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dereference operator:

```
ifstream& ifs1_reference = *ifs1;
```